# Passar valor de Array por checkbox

Tags: php

Tenho esse `checkbox`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seleciona[]" value="<?= $row_questao['codprova'] ?>" >
```

Tenho uma consulta que retorna vários registros e cada registro tem um `checkbox` pra essa linha, preciso que ao marcar algumas ela envie via POST os values para outra página.

Tenho isso feita até agora:

```
if ($_POST) {
   foreach ($_POST["seleciona"] as $checkSeleciona) { // linha 16
       echo $checkSeleciona . ' - ';
   }
}
```

Mas a página ao dar o submit ela retorna com o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: seleciona in C:\xampp\htdocs\sav\cadastraProva.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sav\cadastraProva.php on line 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto é porque está enviando o formulário sem marcar nenhum checkbox, e com isso a array `$_POST["seleciona"]` não existe. Quando um checkbox não é marcado, ele não é enviado no POST.

O `if ($_POST)` está sendo validado porque está enviado no form outro elemento que não sejam os checkbox (ex., algum outro input, select, ou qualquer elemento de formulário com o atributo `name`).

Altere o `if` para `if ($_POST["seleciona"])` para fazer o `foreach` apenas se a array existir.

Comment: Perfeito @Sam, vlw mesmo. a div do checkbox estava fora do form.